# call a function after ChangePage

Tags: jquery-mobile, cordova

I have two pages, the method name is changepage index2.html ... inside this page I would like to make a call to the database and dynamically populate a listview but I can not get to call the function we just change the page ..

on the main page I have this script:

```
 $(document).live( 'pageinit',function(event){  
    $("#changePageButton").click(function() {
        $.mobile.changePage("index2.html", { transition: 'slideup'});  

    });
```

in index2

```
$(document).live( 'pageinit',function(event){   
    alert("OK");            
    });
```

but never displays the alert

Comment: Which versions of jQ and jQM are you using? `.live` is replaced with `.on` after jQ 1.7. Are you placing index2.html code in that page's `head` tag? If yes, out it inside `body` tag. `$.mobile.changePage` loads `body` only and neglect anything else.

Comment: i use jquery-1.8.3 and jquery.mobile-1.3.0, i try in head and out of head...and i try with .live and .on...but doesn't works

Comment: Try `pageshow` and put the code inside index2.html after first `data-role=page`.

Comment: now it works but if I go back again shows me the alert ... if I return to index 2, show me 2 times the alert...thanks

Comment: you can use `$(document).off('pageshow').on('pageshow', function` to kill previous bindings.